# SSIS: Lookup data and merge again

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Somehow I have a feeling that this should be an easy one - but I cannot see how to fix this in a SSIS package.

I have two tables: Order and CustomerMapping. My CustomerMapping table is not containing all my customers, but only customers that have changed Id and CustomerName.

The definitions of the tables are:

Order:
Id (int)
CustomerId (int)
CustomerName (nvarchar(50))

CustomerMapping:
Id (int)
ObsoleteId (int)
CustomerName (nvarchar(50))
ObsoleteCustomerName (nvarchar(50))

Data in Order table is:

```
Id     CustomerId     CustomerName
1      100            Customer 1
2      101            Customer 2
3      102            Customer 3
```

Data in CustomerMapping:

```
Id    ObsoleteId    CustomerName    ObsoleteCustomerName
20    100           New Customer 1  Customer 1
21    101           New Customer 2  Customer 2
```

I want to use the tools provided by the SSIS package to create what I would do like this in SQL:

```
SELECT o.Id,
       CustomerId = ISNULL(cm.Id, o.CustomerId),
       CustomerName = ISNULL(cm.CustomerName, o.CustomerName)
FROM Order AS o
     LEFT JOIN CustomerMapping AS cm ON o.CustomerId = cm.ObsoleteId
```

The result of above query is

```
Id    CustomerId    CustomerName
1     20            New Customer 1
2     21            New Customer 2
3     102           Customer 3
```

I now want to take this result-set and save into a new table.

I know that I can just take the above SQL and do what I want (which might be what I end up doing), but somehow I believe I can make a lookup, merge and/or merge join... But I must admit I cannot really see how I do this without splitting the lookup into two and then having to save from each new "thread".

The above is rather simplified... I have 4 columns which I have to compare and then do some other stuff with the whole lot, before saving it into a new table again, which is why I want to keep a single "thread".

Edit: image added:
[image: I want to to change look up data right after the very first "data source" Source Assistant.]

Comment: Unfortunately my company will not allow me to show the actual screenshots/data as it is confidential :/. But basically I just want to change the ids/names for SOME customers (those in the CustomerMapping table). But I still need the rest of the data to "flow through" as I need all data.

Comment: Added screen shot (after having to anonymise names sigh!) - I want to do my "lookup/merger" right after the very first data source Source Assistant box.

Comment: I still don't understand the specific point at which you're stuck.   Seems like you should be able to merge back together on CustomerID/ObsoleteID.

Comment: You can add a column just to flag which side the data comes from and put a union all in between and split back with a conditional split using the added column.

Comment: Perhaps you've simplified the problem too much. It appears you want to use the data from CustomerMapping where it exists, otherwise the information stored with the Order. I'd likely implement that as a Lookup that ignores non-matches and adds lkp_id, lkp_name, etc to the data flow. Connect a Derived Column to that and put your ISNULL logic there. 2 steps per entity you need to check and it'll be synchronous (fast) all the way versus async with merge/merge joins